# How to get current URL in custom vbo action?

Tags: php, drupal-7, action, vbo

I want to get values like foo, bar  from a current page url like:

```
example.com/foo/bar
```

I've searched everywhere and tried 
`arg()`, `request_path()`, `current_path()`, and even `$_SERVER`, all of this didn't work in my custom action with VBO, I thought this situation also didn't work with `$_GET`.

Anyone can solve this?

Comment: can u use explode function ? explode / And get 3rd value ?
example : explode( "/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );

Comment: It's not work, i use `watchdog('mymodule', print_r($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))`and it just print 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, finally i solved this with `$_SESSION`.